# Firebase: Can decompiling the apk give access to my data and files?

Tags: android, firebase

If someone wanted to reverse engineer my android application by getting the apk file and then customising it to do other things that it shouldn't do. Keeping in mind that the apk file will have the `google-services.json` file that we download from firebase when we create the firebase project to link the android app.

**The question is:**

Even though there is security rules on the real time database or firebase storage that only allows authenticated users. Then the hacker can reverse engineer the app and makes his own application that has the same `google-services.json` file and then when compiling the hacker can create an account and login to the app (which makes him authenticated) and then maybe he can delete and write data to the real time database.

Can someone please explain how the security holds then?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should assume that any code that you ship to a customer could be compromised.  You should assume that the device that they're running it on is under their full control, and that they could change the way your code executes on that device.  The issue isn't so much that your app gets decompiled, it's that you simply can't control the execution environment in any way (unless of course you manufacture the device and have built in your own hardware security).

The data in google-services.json is not private data.  You should assume that the moment you publish an app, everyone will know all the information in that file.  Think of that data as unique identifiers that tell your app where to get data.  There are no passwords or credentials in that file that allow an attacker to do anything that you have not authorized them to do.

It's up to you to use security rules in conjunction with Firebase Authentication in order to control who can do what to the data hosted in Firebase.  It's impossible to stop people from creating random accounts in your app, but it's possible to restrict what they can do.

If you find that your app is subject to some form of abuse, you can shut down the abuser's account, and also contact Firebase support to report abusive behavior.

Comment: So if an attacker, found out that there exists a node called  `chat_node` from my java code, and knowing that this `chat_node` must be writable by authenticated users......then the attacker can maybe write null to the high node which is `chat_node` and all other users data will be deleted...is this a possibility?

Comment: If that is a possibility then this is a huge security issue.

Comment: If you allow it, then it can happen.  You need to design your security rules to disallow actions that you don't want to happen.

Comment: Doug I understand what you are saying, but my question is this: if an attacker can get my apk and json is found in the apk......the only step that is left is to recompile my project in android studio and an attacker can change stuff?

Comment: is it possible or the attacker needs some key to do that?

Comment: shouldn't my app be a special instance of my firebase console?

Comment: I think you're missing my main point - you have control over who can do what in your project, and you do that through security rules.  This is your only way of controlling access.  Everything else can be compromised.

Comment: How would you design a security rules in the example I gave you about the `chat_node` case? Can you please tell me.

Comment: Now you're asking a completely different question than the one you started out with.  Please formulate a new question on Stack Overflow with a problem description, what you tried to do to solve it, and what didn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same situation couple of months back.

As I understand, the moment you generate your project ( Creating it from Firebase console or Android studio) it will ask for a SHA-1 key.

This SHA-1 key is unique and serves as the authorization from your project to connect to the services of Firebase, for example, if a user has your google-services.json it will be hard to them to even log in or authenticate without a SHA-1 key that allows them to use your project.

I was also inspecting the google-services.json and there is the SHA1-1 with the package names.

```
 "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.packagename.debug",
            "certificate_hash": "SHA1-KEY"
          }
```

If you need to add a new SHA-1 you will also need to either authenticate using Gmail to go to the Firebase console and add it yourself (in which case is nearly impossible that a hacker can access to your Gmail account) or do the same thing from Android studio and sync the project.

As I said before, this is how I understand this situation, also, little research from securing API keys told that you need to be worried about client-side APIs than public APIS in your app.

The thing is that encrypting client side your APIS exposes the encryption code and can be decoded to, this is why sometimes it will be better to run some sort of a function from Firebase and send the sensible APIS to your project.

Telling it again, I'm answering with how I understand it works from having and inspecting the projects that I have, this is not an official answer so take it with tweezers.

Comment: But does it mean that a reversed code can change my data nodes if data nodes can be accessed by authentication?

Comment: I think that the attacker needs to have the sha1 of  his project inside your firebase console , and that , without a Gmail login is not possible

Comment: So are you saying that once I link my app with firebase a sha 1 is created on the firebase console?

Comment: Once you link it with Android studio , yes , and it requested too when you create the project manually, you can go to project settings and see your package name and sha1 there

Comment: Yeah but when an attacker get my apk file, it already is linked with firebase...so the only thing left is to recompile in android studio and start writing stuff to my database?

Comment: If the attacker makes a new Android project with your google-services , the package of the project can be the same, but not the sha1 , when the attacker tries to login into your firebase project it will be rejected because the sha1 key is not matching with the same project, this is how I understand it, when you move your project to a new PC , you need to either manually add the sha1 of that project into firebase console , or sync it with Android studio

Comment: To sync the project with Android studio you should be authenticated with the Gmail account you used to create the project at Firebase, the same applies to the web console

Comment: The attacker can know your sha1 but can't post it to your firebase project since the google-services data is client side and will not change unless you sync it with firebase , either downloading a new google-services or sync with Android studio